# why does the thread still run after it released lock?

Tags: java, synchronization, deadlock

This is the example in java tutorial of Oracle about Lock object. Someone please confirms whether I interpreted the code correctly.

I will consider only the first thread, because the other works the same way.

First, it acquires the lock of alphonse, and accesses the method impendingBow. The method now tries to assign the two locks of the two instances to the thread. If the thread cannot acquire both locks, it releases the one it acquires. This is when I am stucking. if the thread releases the lock, the other may access to both instance, and the first thread should stop executing right after it releases the lock. But actually it does not. It still returns the boolean value and continues to run the else statement in bow method. Why does it possibly happen? I thought that like synchronized code, the thread should stop executing until it gets the lock again.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.Random;

public class Safelock {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public boolean impendingBow(Friend bower) {
            Boolean myLock = false;
            Boolean yourLock = false;
            try {
                myLock = lock.tryLock();
                yourLock = bower.lock.tryLock();
            } finally {
                if (! (myLock && yourLock)) {
                    if (myLock) {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                    if (yourLock) {
                        bower.lock.unlock();
                    }
                }
            }
            return myLock && yourLock;
        }

        public void bow(Friend bower) {
            if (impendingBow(bower)) {
                try {
                    System.out.format("%s: %s has"
                        + " bowed to me!%n",
                        this.name, bower.getName());
                    bower.bowBack(this);
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                    bower.lock.unlock();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.format("%s: %s started"
                    + " to bow to me, but saw that"
                    + " I was already bowing to"
                    + " him.%n",
                    this.name, bower.getName());
            }
        }

        public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has" +
                " bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }

    static class BowLoop implements Runnable {
        private Friend bower;
        private Friend bowee;

        public BowLoop(Friend bower, Friend bowee) {
            this.bower = bower;
            this.bowee = bowee;
        }

        public void run() {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int n = 0; n <5;n++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random()*1000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                bowee.bow(bower);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Friend alphonse =
            new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston =
            new Friend("Gaston");
        new Thread(new BowLoop(alphonse, gaston)).start();
        new Thread(new BowLoop(gaston, alphonse)).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think a thread should stop executing _after_ it releases a `Lock` object?

Comment: I relate lock object with synchronized code, which only allows a thread run a code if it acquires lock, and block the thread if it does not.

Comment: How can it acquire a lock if it isn't running?

Comment: The other way around is my question, why it released lock but still run. And I not disagree if a thread is running in a synchronized code, it already acquire lock. But I am not sure with lock object.

Comment: Locks are used to surround critical sections, so only one thread can access that section at a time. If a thread has released a lock, then it is no longer in a critical section and shouldn't have to wait on anything.

Comment: Thanks. But is it true that with synchronized code, there is no way to release the lock as unlock method of lock object?

Comment: That's right. Execution has to leave the `synchronized` block for the thread to unlock the corresponding object monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are subtle difference between synchronized blocks, `Lock.lock()`, `Lock.tryLock()` and `Lock.tryLock(timeout)`.

The `tryLock` method acquires the lock only if it is not held by another thread at the time of invocation. So when it can not acquire the lock it returns immediately.

The `lock` method will wait until the lock is available, while waiting that thread is dormant. The same goes for synchronizing code with the synchronized statement. The thread will wait until it can acquire the lock on that block of code.

The `tryLock(timeout)` method will wait until the lock is available or until the timeout expires.

More or less described in the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

For the behavior that you expect you change the `tryLock` statement with `lock` and you'll notice that the threads will get into a deadlock eventually.

Comment: You said: The tryLock method acquires the lock only if it is not held by another thread at the time of invocation. So when it can not acquire the lock it returns immediately. what do you mean "return immediately"? it means the method continues to run the rest of code?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. The method returns immediately in the sense that it doesn't stop to wait for the lock to become available. You can tell it acquired the lock by looking at the return value stored in `myLock` and `yourLock`.


In the example you can replace `tryLock` with `tryLock(timeout)`. Then add a bit of code around to statement to measure the time it takes. You'll see that `tryLock` never takes long while `tryLock(timeout)` will often as long as the timeout duration.

Answer (score 0):

The thread will not stop executing when it releases the lock. It stops executing if:

1. It tries to lock a lock but cannot (won't stop execution here because you use trylock)
2. It explicitly yields control, e.g. by sleeping (sleep())
3. The scheduler decides it likes the other thread more now. For all intents and purposes, you should assume this is a random event.

Neither of these things happen here, so the one thread continues executing until 3) happens.